# How to choose maximum lag length for VAR selection

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, model-selection, vector-autoregression, lags

For vector auto-regression models, I understand the optimum lag length is chosen using AIC, BIC, Hannan-Quinn criterion, etc. But how do you select what your maximum lag length should be? lag.max=10 seems standard (based on examples I have researched), and when I put use that criteria, my optimum lag length is 10. When I use lag.max=15, my optimum is 14. Is there a way to choose a maximum lag length based on your data or on auto-correlation plot or any other method?